# RegEx for extracting placeholder matches

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have this string

```py
template = "Hello my name is <name>, I'm <age>."
```

And I want to test if my strings match that template and anything can be in place of the placeholders. The placeholders start and end with brackets like this `<place holder here>`. E.g this string would match

```py
string = "Hello my name is John Doe, I'm 30 years old."
```

I also want to extract parts of the string that substitute the placeholders. For the example above, I want to get the list:

```py
['John Doe', '30 years old']
```

I'm able to extract the placeholders of the template using the pattern `<(.*?)>` for regex, but I'm currently stuck on how to extract the actual substitutions from the string. I need a generic approach and I don't want to hardcode the pattern to match the full template because I have many templates to check. Is there a clever way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically build a regex using the template. Then match it against any input string.

```
import re

template = "Hello my name is <name>, I'm <age>."
pattern = "^" + re.escape(template) + "$"
pattern = re.sub("<[^>]+>", "(?P\g<0>.*)", pattern)
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)

string = "Hello my name is John Doe, I'm 30 years old."
match = regex.match(string)

match.group(0)
#=> "Hello my name is John Doe, I'm 30 years old."
match.group("name")
#=> 'John Doe'
match.group("age")
#=> '30 years old'
match.groups()
#=> ('John Doe', '30 years old')
```

The only restriction upon the template is that valid regex group names should be used.

You could lift this, by simply not using named regex groups.

```
# replacing
pattern = re.sub("<[^>]+>", "(?P\g<0>.*)", pattern)
# with
pattern = re.sub("<[^>]+>", "(.*)", pattern)
```

Combine this with cross-referencing the placeholders from the template and you have more naming options.

```
placeholders = re.findall("<[^>]+>", template)
placeholders = list(map(lambda match: match[1:-1], placeholders))

dict(zip(placeholders, match.groups()))
#=> {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': '30 years old'}
```

Comment: This is my first time using any Python. If you spot newbie code/optimisations please let me know.

Comment: Change `"<[^>]+>"` into `"<[^>]*>"` to allow empty placeholders.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

If the desired outputs are followed by exact punctuation mentioned in the question, we can simply use an expression similar to:

```
is\s(.+?),|([0-9].+)\.
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uuZkPK/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"is\s(.+?),|([0-9].+)\."

test_str = "Hello my name is John Doe, I'm 30 years old."

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I want. I want a more generic approach. Basically I want to create a function `func` that returns `['John Doe', '30 years old']` if I call `func(template, string)`. `func` should also work for other templates as well. The punctuations don't matter. The placeholders (with a pair of brackets `<>`) do.